# Html.PagedListPager Not Working on .Net 4.5.1

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, razor

There is a function called @Html.PagedListPager() that does pagination and it works in all my other projects, but in this project it cannot generate a URL, so when I filter some specific things, it shows the dates and times in the filtering areas, and it shows how many pages there are as 1 2 3, but when I click on the 2nd page, I get the pagination button below. When I look at the payload section, it does not send anything, it only sends that the page is 2 and naturally the filters are set to 0. What could be the problem?

This function :

```
<ul class="pagination">
    @Html.PagedListPager(Url, new PagerHtmlRenderer(currentPageNumber: Model.CurrentPageNumber, pageSize: Model.PageSize, totalNumberOfItems: Model.TotalNumberOfItems, actionName: "AllStoreScore", controllerName: "Report", routeValues: Url.GetRouteValueDictionaryForList(Model), pageRouteValueName: "page"))

 
</ul>
```

Solve this problem or way.